¿Cuál es el primer uso registrado de la palabra persona en el Español?
Según RAE, persona viene del latín,

Del latín persōna 'máscara de actor', 'personaje teatral',
'personalidad', 'persona', este del etrusco φersu, y este del griego
πρόσωπον prósōpon.

Persona RAE
Ahora yo en realidad quisiera sabe cuál es el primer uso registrado que existe de esta palabra en Español, o al menos, uno muy antiguo que se conozca en algún libro, obra, etc

No está claro en qué momento el español pasó a ser un idioma aparte y hasta qué año seguía siendo un dialecto del latín. LA pregunta, por lo tanto, carece de sentido.

@tac ahora estás hablando Español no? O Latín? La pregunta también dice, o al menos uno muy antiguo. Si alguien publica uno tan antiguo que está en duda si es Español, lo puedes comentar

Exactamente, tal como decís, la pregunta no deja de ser absurda porque presupone que hay un momento de la historia en el que el latín dejó de ser latín y pasó a ser español, cuando no hay ningún consenso sobre ello. Primero deberías preguntar eso. Segundo, debido a que no hay una respuesta unívoca, no existe ningún 'primer uso registrado'. Simplemente la palabra se heredó, como muchas otras más.

La palabra “persona” en español proviene del latín “persona” que se usaba para referirse una máscara teatral o a un papel en el teatro. Comenzó a usarse en el sentido humano en textos en español en el siglo XIII. El término “persona” se usaba en la época medieval para referirse a seres humanos en general, no solo a personajes teatrales.

Buenas, Charly, bienvenido al sitio. Pablo ha sido muy específico en su pregunta: Primer uso registrado de la palabra "persona" en castellano. "Textos del siglo XIII" sin incluir a qué texto te refieres no parece responder a la pregunta.

De todas formas, la pregunta en sí ya es un disparate así que el espíritu de la respuesta va acorde a ello.
